# Simple SQL question

Tags: mysql

I'm try to resolve this but I don't understand?

#### My query

```
Select FirstName, City
FROM Customer
WHERE City NOT IN ('Paris')
```

#### Error

> Your answer does not contain the expression <>

[image: SQL Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are using for this, but apparently it is looking for a very specific answer.  Your answer will work, but it looks like they are expecting

```
WHERE City <> 'Paris'
```

This would also be valid:

```
WHERE City != 'Paris'
```

but you would probably get the same error.